# berlekamp massey feedback polynomial

Tags: stream-cipher

I have a couple of polynomials to find. Can anybody guide me with the steps to find the feedback polynomial using berlekamp massey's algorithm.

Example:

Key fragment: 10100100001001101001011
seed: 11010000101

The online tool gives me this answer: x^11 + x^2 + 1
whereas the correct answer is:  x^10 + x^8 + 1
Thanks

Comment: Recently, there were a similar question, it might help you. [Decrypting Ciphertext with partial Key Fragment using LFSR and Berlekamp-Massey](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66102/decrypting-ciphertext-with-partial-key-fragment-using-lfsr-and-berlekamp-massey/66307#66307)

Comment: @kelalaka. I looked into that linked. "Use Berlakamp-Massay algorithm to find a shortest LFSR (need not to be unique). Online version is used.
The output is given as x16+x12+x3+x1+1" This was your comment on that post. But i want the steps on how to get polynomials without using the online tool.
and this is the online website i was referring to: http://bma.bozhu.me/ I want to practice and be able to solve by using the berlekamp's algorithm so that i could solve it in my exam. I am unable to grasp the steps mentioned on wikipedia so was asking for some help as i have a lot of questions to sove.

Comment: Have a look at [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=berlekamp+massey) some might help you or wait for a full answer here from someone. note : hand calculation might be very troublesome.

Comment: Note: if you write your step, people can be more helpful.