# Understanding LFSRs and Berlekamp-Massey Algorithm

Tags: algorithm-design, lfsr

I have a tutorial question which focuses on LFSRs and Berlekamp-Massey Algo (which is totally out of my syllabus). Please forgive me if my questions seem stupid.

I'm given these information:

> {"lfsr":{"seed":"1100110001100101"},"keyFragment":"101010001111001110000110111001101","cipherText":"bb0000e911b4238a6ca3"}

My seed is 1100110001100101 (16 bits)

My key fragment is 101010001111001110000110111001101 (33 bits)

My cipher text is bb0000e911b4238a6ca3 (in hexadecimal)

> Apply the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm on the key stream fragment you
>   were given to obtain the feedback polynomial that generated the key.
>   For full marks, you have to implement the algorithm yourself, attach
>   key parts of the algorithm to the report as an appendix and describe
>   briefly which bit of the implementation you found the most
>   challenging. If you use someone else’s code or an online service you
>   will not be awarded full marks; in this case make sure you acknowledge
>   the source of the code or service you use.

I'm using an online calculator and my LFSR is x^16 + x^12 + x^3 + x^1 + 1.
Which means that my tap positions are 1, 3, 12 and 16.

> Question 6: Generate the full key stream in order to be able to decrypt the
>   cipher text you intercepted (i.e. what you were given)

From this question, I have no idea what to do. I don't exactly understand how multiple taps work. I understand that with one tap position you are able to XOR and obtain last bit for every cycle. My fundamentals are weak, and most resources come with a difficult mathematical explanation which I cannot understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrypting Ciphertext with partial Key Fragment using LFSR and Berlekamp-Massey](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66102/decrypting-ciphertext-with-partial-key-fragment-using-lfsr-and-berlekamp-massey). If the answer does not satisfies you, let us know.

Comment: @kelalaka it is a duplicate, however, my output is this `keystream       : 11001100011001010110000110011101011110011101000101010001111001110000110111001101
\j  pliantext   : i╣GàFE
`, and i've only replace the seed and cipher text.

Comment: Did you replaced the seed? Order is important.

Comment: @kelalaka let me double check my inputs. i replaced the seed and cipher text. my cipher text is in hexadecimal. hence, i have to convert it to binary myself.

Comment: @kelalaka thank you, something is wrong with my inputs. the code is working correctly. thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome and welcome to Cryptography.