# Building an LFSR logical bitmap using characteristic polynomials

Tags: lfsr

How would one build an LFSR logical map, with a characteristic polynomial such as

$$P(x) = x^4 + x^3 + 1$$?

Also, how would you interpret it, and what would you do to do the reverse it in order to create a characteristic polynomial from an LFSR map?

Comment: Hint: calculate the reciprocal of $P(x)$ then use feedback polynomial as in [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66307/18298)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I am able to understand this much better, thanks kelalaka!

Comment: Use sageMath . It has great functions to calculate characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipocal $P^*(x)$ of polynomial $$P(x)= a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_nx^n$$ of degree $n = deg(P(x))$  is given by;

$$P^*(x) = a_n + a_{n-1}x + \cdots + a_0x^n = x^n P(x^{-1})$$

The feedback polynomial defines the tap points of LFSR. The characteristic polynomial and is the reciprocal of feedback. Therefore;

Let $P^*(x)= x^4 \cdot P(1/x) = 1 + x + x^4 $ be the feedback polynomial LFSR   calculated by the recipocal of characteristic polynomial $P(x)$. Then the taps of the LFSR as follows;

[image]

For further reading in this subject, [Golomb's classic book](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/578271) is advised.

---

<sub>The image is produced with the [LFSR drawing library](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89828/18298).</sub>