# Is there a library that output LFSR images given parameters?

Tags: stream-cipher, lfsr

I'm looking for a library that given parameters; feedback polynomial, initial values then it will produce $\LaTeX$ / Tikz codes to include in Latex documents or LFSR images. Is there such a library?

---

This Question and answer are provided to test the limits of this [Meta question](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1313/18298).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a python library [LFSR-Automatic-Draw](https://github.com/kelalaka153/LFSR-Automatic-Draw)  that can output $\LaTeX$ Tikz code and that can be converted to PNG images by

`pdflatex -shell-escape lfsr.tex`

The library has many parameters to draw;

- One can print the feedback polynomial on the bottom
- One can enable/disable printing the name of the boxes
- One can  enable/disable printing the initial values
- Font size, box sizes, colors, arrow sizes, etc.

Sample outputs are

[image]

[image]

[image]

And, the library now can output multiple images per clock that can be converted to loop-animation

[image]