# Polynomial notation of LFSR

Tags: lfsr

I was following along with [Christof Paar's lecture on Linear Feedback Shift Registers](https://youtu.be/sKUhFpVxNWc?t=3758).   He explains the structure coherently as a set of flip flops where the 'taps' are defined by a bit vector (0 for no tap on that flip flop,  1 for a tap on that flip flop).  This makes perfect sense to me.

But then he brings up the point that people describe an LFSR not as a set of flip flops and a bit vector to define the taps, but as a polynomial equation.

I don't understand what this polynomial representation is trying to do.

`P(x) = x^4 + x + 1`    would represent a network of 4 flip flops, the right-most two being 'tapped' to XOR into the new bit.

What is the value `P(x)` supposed to be? In fact, I'm not even sure what the `x` value is.  Further mysteries to me: (1) the far right flip flop is represented by 1. Is this shorthand for `x^0` ?    (2)  the `x^4` term.... the four flip-flops are labelled 0,1,2,3. So why a power-four term?

Makes me wonder if this 'equation' isn't really an equation you expect to emit a value to use, but some kind of hand-wavy way to just describe the architecture of a LFSR?

Comment: [Visual guide](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/89829/18298) and $P(x) = 0$ as usual!

Comment: By the way, generating functions in combinatorics are based on the same idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the value $P(x)$ supposed to be?

Nothing. We are interested in the *coefficients* of the polynomial $P(x)$, which are restricted to the [Booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) $\{0,1\}$. These coefficients reflect the wiring of the LFSR. For other polynomials, they could reflect the state of the LFSR. We seldom¹ need to evaluate that polynomial $P(x)$, or other polynomials we use, for a particular value of $x$, or even specify the set $x$ belongs to. Think of $x$ as an unspecified variable, be it in integers $\mathbb Z$, rationals $\mathbb Q$, reals $\mathbb R$, complexes $\mathbb C$, as you see fit; and confidently perform arithmetic on such polynomials per the standard rules of algebra, modified by $1+1=0$ (equivalently, by reducing all coefficients of polynomials modulo $2$).

> The far right flip flop is represented by $1$. Is this shorthand for $x^0$?

Yes. Another reason we write $1$ is to avoid having to define $0^0$.

> The four flip-flops are labelled $0,1,2,3$. So why a power-four term?

The degree-four term is only in $P(x)$, which represents the wiring of the LFSR, not the state of it's flip-flops. When dealing with the state, it will be represented by a polynomial $S(x)$ of degree at most three.

Also: when we reduce any polynomial modulo the polynomial $P(x)$, the remainder $S(x)$ has degree strictly lower that $P(x)$, thus it's coefficients (typically a new state of the LFSR) fit the four flip-flops.

Yet another way to see it is that the term $x^4$ in $P(x)$ corresponds to the bit that gets out of the shift register when we shift by one bit (equivalently, multiply the state by $x$), while the other bits correspond to adjustments of the new states of each flip-flop.

> Makes me wonder if this 'equation' isn't really an equation you expect to emit a value to use, but some kind of hand-wavy way to just describe the architecture of a LFSR?

Indeed, $P(x)$ is about the architecture of the LFSR. The representation as polynomial $P(x)$ for architecture and $S(x)$ for state is useful to establish properties of LFSRs. In particular, for a LFSR in Galois form, the state evolves per $S_{i+1}(x)=S_i(x)\,x\bmod P(x)$, from which it follows $S_i(x)=S_0(x)\,x^i\bmod P(x)$.

Note: here, $\bmod$ yields the remainder per [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), again with coefficients in the Booleans.

---

¹ Exceptions: evaluation of $P(x)$ at $x=1$ in the Booleans, or $x=2$ for the integers, yield occasionally interesting values.