# Question about obtaining a keystream from a linear-feedback shift register

Tags: shift-register

For a homework question we are obtaining a keystream from a LFSR and I am slightly confused on which digits are used as the key.

For example I have this table here,

```
b5 → b4 + b1
t   B5  B4  B3  B2  B1
1   1   0   1   0   1
2   1   1   0   1   0
3   1   1   1   0   1
4   0   1   1   1   0
5   1   0   1   1   1
6   1   1   0   1   1
7   0   1   1   0   1
8   0   0   1   1   0
9   0   0   0   1   1
10  1   0   0   0   1
11  1   1   0   0   0
12  1   1   1   0   0
13  1   1   1   1   0
14  1   1   1   1   1
15  0   1   1   1   1
16  0   0   1   1   1
17  1   0   0   1   1
18  1   1   0   0   1
19  0   1   1   0   0
20  1   0   1   1   0
21  0   1   0   1   1
22  0   0   1   0   1
23  1   0   0   1   0
24  1   1   0   0   1
25  0   1   1   0   0
```

As you can see rows 19 through 24 will repeat. If I were to use B1 for the keystream, would I only include digits from rows 19-24 in the key since they are repeating or would I include all digits from t=1 to t=32?

Comment: Welcome to our site. B1 since it is the output, see the [images](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/89828/18298). Repeats, yes, in your steps, not yet! Can you show me two stages that the internal values of the LFSR are the same?

Comment: @kelalaka I'm not sure I understand. Once you get past entry 18, the table will repeat in 6 row intervals since it will keep looping back to 01100

Comment: You should have some errors in your calculations. LFSR are periodic, they don't have tails to enter the loop. With 5 stages, you can have a period of $2^5-1$ if the polynomial is primitive ( m-sequence).

Comment: Try this [sagemath cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVjTEKwzAMRXedwqMFHtKsoat7iBBCMQqYqlIapUNuX8e4hSKQvt5HX9Fd3S36HiGCFh19h4Pjqi4IDzqKHDVw0FI8DW7JfNrjSbgxKaDvwKhMXmybjV5vkkS-BITzIgjCumXZvREC2F9CLW1df-S7N3dqAfVBUhFKe1aZV-VD9Jnv7A3xA9JXP1A=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), however, no online Berlekamp-Massey. [SageMath LFSR page](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/lfsr.html)